# Netbeans PHP autocomplete

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

how could I add an autocomplete for PHP build-in functions like htmlentities or var_dump?
The autocompleter work for my classes but there's not autocompletion for functions like mentioned above.

Comment: I have filed that as a Netbeans bug: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=207473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a "Global Include Path" in Options > PHP > General.

On Mac OS X with MacPorts this should be `/opt/local/lib/php`, but in the documentation at [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html) I didn't find any hints, what to set on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans will surely find all your classes, but only when you declare them explicitly, like this:

```
    <?php
class example {
   function getData(){
       include("data.php");
       $myData = new data();
       $myData->... will show all your classes.
    }
}
```

But if you get an object from another class (that's my case) you need to "tell" netbeans what type is that variable:

```
<?php
class example {
    function getData($myData){ 
    // $myData is an object from class data() instantiated on another part of the code. NetBeans can't know this
    /* @var $myData data */
    $myData->... ///will show methods and properties
    }
}
```